# Parenthesis in a file name -- batch conversion

Tags: bash, filenames, parentheses

I have a bunch of files that contain parenthesis, like

```
long_file_name (12).txt
```

(note the space before the number)
I would like to extract all the numbers from the file names. How can I do that?
I have found this thread [stackoverflow link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125776/error-with-a-file-name-containing-parentheses) but it didn't help -- the problem is that I want to assign filename to a variable and not change each of the files separately.

Thanks for all help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in bash by using the variable interpolation/substitution:

```
$ F="long_file_name (12).txt"
$ echo ${F/*(/}
12).txt
$ G=${F/*(/}; echo ${G/)*/}
12
$ G=${F/*(/}; H=${G/)*/}; echo $H
12
$
```

In short, this will give you just the number in parentheses from a filename:

```
F="long_file_name (12).txt"
G=${F/*(/}; H=${G/)*/}; echo $H
```

If you have filenames in other formats, please supply more examples to test with.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rename all files having parenthesis in their filenanme, you can use this bash script:

```
cd /path/to/my/files
for i in *; do
   [[ -f "$i" ]] && { [[ "$i" == "${i/ (*)/}" ]] || mv -v "$i" "${i/ (*)/}"; }
done
```

It looks all files in the directory and check if the filename contains parenthesis. If yes, the renaming is done.

Instead, if you want to rename the files with their number, use this:

```
for i in *; do
   if [[ -f "$i" ]]; then 
     newname=$(echo "$i" | sed 's/.*(\([^)]\+\))[^.]*\(.*\)$/\1\2/')
     [[ "$newname" == "$i" ]] || mv -v "$i" "$newname"
   fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have to do quite the opposite -- extract numbers and use them as filenames :)

Comment: @Michal I understood the oppsite... Anyway answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the naming convention of your file remains like: `long_file_name ([0-9][0-9]).txt`, then you can capture the filenames in a variable using `find` command.

```
cd /path/to/files/
var=$(find . -type f -name "long_file_name ([0-9][0-9]).txt"|sed 's,^./,,g')
echo "${var}" |rev |cut -c6-7 |rev
```

This will give the numbers inside the file_names

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice idea, but how can I assign the extracted numbers to filenames? i.e. mv long_file_name (XX).txt to XX.txt?